# How to add ul li to div on textbox change and remove ul li from div with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I have a form in which on textbox change event I need to create ul and li with textbox text and if user wants to remove the added item then user should able to remove with one confirmation.

I am able to add the ul and li with below jquery but I want to know how to remove specific (item with user wants to remove) ul and li from the div.

```
<div id="divDynamic"></div>

$('#txtItem').blur(function () {
        var addedItems = [];
        var text = $(this).val();
        if ($('li:contains(' + text + ')').length === 0) {
            var _tempUL = $('<ul/>').addClass('navlist');
            $("#divDynamic").append(_tempUL);
            var liText = $('<li/>').addClass('btn-gradient').html(text);
                _tempUL.append(liText);
                _tempUL.append('<li class="close"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/close.png" /></a></li>');
            addedItems.push(text);
          }
    });
```

Some one please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: var text = $(this).val();
if($('li:contains(text).length){
  // your code
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Replace below line

```
_tempUL.append('<li class="close"><a href="#"><img src="/Images/close.png" /></a></li>');
```

to

```
_tempUL.append('<li class="close"><a href="#" class="removeLi"><img src="/Images/close.png" /></a></li>');
```

then put this jQuery code

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.removeLi', function() {

    $(this).parent().prev('li.btn-gradient').remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

Comment: how can I get the value or text of item which is getting removed?

Comment: $(document).on( 'click', '.removeLi', function() {

    $(this).parent().prev('li.btn-gradient').remove();
    $(this).parent().remove();

});

Comment: you can use var value =  $(this).parent().prev('li.btn-gradient').text(); before remove it.